# @JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL) not working as expected

Tags: java, web-services

I have added `@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)` annotation on Response class.

```
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
public class Response {

  @JsonProperty
  private String message;

 // getter-setters
}
```

If the value is null the property does not include in JSON

But still I am getting this property as a NULL.

```
{
"message": null
}
```

What can be the reason ? Am I missing anything ?

Comment: Isn't that the point of the Include.NON_NULL annotation? If you want all fields included then remove the annotation. It probably worked because @JsonSerialize(include = Inclusion.NON_NULL) is deprecated.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I tried

```
@JsonSerialize(include = Inclusion.NON_NULL)
```

intead of

```
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
```

and it worked as expected.

Comment: Thank you! I was having this problem in my Spring project, using version 2.3.3 of Jackson.

Comment: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonSerialize.Inclusion is now deprecated :-/

Comment: @LeventDivilioglu, see the above comment. It's deprecated in later versions of Jackson

Comment: `@JsonSerialize(include = whatever)` is now deprecated. This is not the correct way to do it with recent versions of Jackson.

Comment: from java 8, for a field use this @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)

Answer (score 7):

This is the correct way of using it. This I valid from jdk 8 +.

`@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)`

more information is available in :
[json-include-non-empty](https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/misc/jackson/json-include-non-empty.html)

Answer (score 4):

I encountered the same issue
Solved by using

```
@JsonInclude(value = Include.NON_EMPTY, content = Include.NON_NULL)
```

Comment: I have the same issue as OP, but this had no effect for me. :-/

Answer (score 3):

I am using Java Spring & in that, I am implementing like :

**Class Level:**

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;

        @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
        public class Student {

            String name;
            //getter-setter
    }
```

You can also implement it on elements level of class :

**Elements Level:**

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;

        @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
        public class Student {

            String name;

            @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
            String address;
            //getter-setter
    }
```

Comment: This one is worked for me, 
just make sure it really above of your response class
```@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
class ResponseObject{

}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is deprecated:

```
@JsonSerialize(include = JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_NULL)
```

Instead use:

```
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
```

Answer (score 1):

Add @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL) at the attribute level instead of class level as show below :

```
public class Response {
  @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
  private String message;
  // getters and setters
}
```

You can also change your class to record and add the json property then you don't have to write the getters and setters:

```
public record Response(@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL) String message) {}
```