# How to send only certain parameters of the model in a request?

Tags: java, rest-assured

I have a question. How to send only selected parameters in a JSON?
For example I have a class:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
public class City {

private String name;
private String country;
private long population;
private String postCode;
}
```

If I would like to make changes and send a **PUT** request which allows only "population" and "postCode".

Instead when I am sending a put request, all the parameters from the model **City** class are sent.

Comment: I tested your model and it worked as expected. It's only create a json with selected keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add the Jackson annotation `@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)` an easy selection could be made, by setting all fields that you want to exclude to `null`.

See also:

- [@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL) not working as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26256720/jsonincludeinclude-non-null-not-working-as-expected)
- Baeldung tutorial: [Ignore Null Fields with Jackson](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-ignore-null-fields)